# Submitting Form Data to Excel Online

Tags: html, excel, forms, export-to-excel, excel-online

Is there any way to submit data from my html form to a row in an excel online spreadsheet for free?

Any help would be appreciated

David

I have tried all sorts of methods including combining jotform and zapier, but that doesn't allow enough submissions per month. I currently use [NoCodeForm](https://nocodeform.io), but I have to add to the spreadsheet manually.